# How to add observable collection item

Tags: observable

Currently, i'm trying to understand observables. I'm using zen-observables. Following code is not doing what i expect.

```
import Observable from "zen-observable";

const foobar = [];

Observable.from(foobar).subscribe(x => console.log(x));

foobar.push("test");
foobar.push("foobar");

setTimeout(() => {
  foobar.push("123");
}, 500);
```

"123" is never logged to console. So, how can i add an item asynchronously?

[codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/zenobservable-j5g4k)

Answer (score 0):

You did everything right. the "123" value was pushed after 0.5 a seconde. you can see at this code [codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/embed/quirky-shirley-nr4v7?fontsize=14)  that the 123 is appearing in the console. If you want to use setTimeout to be asynchronously you can use async - await like this [codesandbox example2](https://codesandbox.io/embed/musing-bird-y8dfc?fontsize=14)

***Edited***

O.k now after I understand your question better, I try to answer your question:

1. **First, let's understand Observable better** - Observable it's a design pattern that came from OOP methodology, the main use of Observable to store data of other objects (or in javascript case any other data), and they have listener function that does something. A good resource for understanding - http://anasfirdousi.com/understanding-observable-patterns-behind-observables-rxjs-rx.html
2. **In your specific case** -

   - In the first case :

     const observable = new Observable(observer => {
      myObserver = observer;
     });
     // You give the Observable variable he can listen to.
   - In the second case :

     const foobar = [];
     foobar.push("test");
     foobar.push("foobar");
     Observable.from(foobar).subscribe(x => console.log(x));
     // you just add a new "list" to the Observable, but you din't created the Obsrvable
3. **Conclusion** - I the first case you are created the "Observable" and you can use the "subscribe" method asynchronously or synchronously way like this code:

   import Observable from "zen-observable";

   let myObserver;

   const observable = new Observable(observer => {
     myObserver = observer;
   });

   observable.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
   myObserver.next("1");
   myObserver.next("2");

   setTimeout(() => {
     myObserver.next("3");
   }, 3000);

[codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/embed/gracious-cache-c8bqo?fontsize=14)

As you can see, the 3 will print after 3 seconds, it means you can use the Observable synchronously and asynchronously (the setTimeout make it asynchronously). You can only use it as this way because in this way you created the Observable and didn't just save the list(like your question code).

I hope it helped you understand better

Comment: sorry, i don't get it. What if my subscription lives outside setTimeout()? You just moved the observable und subscription to the setTimeout callback.

Comment: As you can see it just an explanation of the problem you asked "codesandbox example" about how it works. the solution is in "codesandbox example 2"

Comment: Ok sorry, then my question wasn't precise enough. What i'm trying to achieve is a subscription which triggers when the observable data changed like in my code example. Here is a working example but it looks really weird to me:
https://codesandbox.io/s/zenobservable-bopxd

Comment: Hi @Remownz I edited my answer, hope it's more helpful now

Comment: i think, i've got it :) Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

For every observable.subscribe call a new subscription observer will be created. So you could push it to an observers array to notify all observers later.

```
import Observable from "zen-observable";

const observers = [];

const observable = new Observable(observer => {
  observer.next("initial data");
  observers.push(observer);
});

observable.subscribe(x => console.log("first subscriber", x));
observable.subscribe(x => console.log("second subscriber", x));

function update(data) {
  observers.forEach(observer => observer.next(data));
}

setTimeout(() => {
  update("updated data");
}, 5000);
```